# HTML5 peertopeerconnection()

Tags: html

Am I right in thinking that the [HTML5 peertopeerconnection()](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080122/#peer-to-peer) for enabling peer to peer communication between different computers browsing the same site has been dropped from the [latest draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100304/) and has not been implemented? ([see this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032006/will-html5-allow-web-apps-to-make-peer-to-peer-http-connections) for more details).

Comment: Is this a valid question?  Go to the latest draft and perform a CTRL+F for the above named constructor or find the Network Connections section, if it still exists.

Comment: I couldn't find any mention of it being dropped. Maybe it's been renamed or something. I can't find any discussion bar that stack-overflow question I linked. If nothing else, it would be good to help someone who might spend a couple hours trying to dig up info on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gone and replaced by WebSockets. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/pubnotes/Overview.html#network_wd2.

Comment: Thanks. Essentially it is gone in it's original form.