# Do websockets allow for p2p (browser to browser) communication?

Tags: javascript, ajax, websocket, p2p

To clarify when I ask about browser to browser communication I mean without a server in between forwarding message.  I would like to implement something like this for a game.  If p2p in websockets isn't possible are there similar alternatives?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, but no browser has a working implementation, and I believe it's now part of the [stream API.](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/commands.html#peer-to-peer-connections)

Comment: The W3C now drafts the [WebRTC](http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/) spec talking about Peer-to-Peer connections amongst others things.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

No. Browsers can only initiate WebSockets connections, not receive them. The [W3C browser API spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) only defines how to start an outbound connection.

You can make an application that would both initiate and accept WebSockets connections, but browsers do not do this.

You might look at [Pusher App](http://pusherapp.com/) which you could use to build a WebSockets application with multiple clients. The service provides up to 20 simultaneous WebSockets clients for free (you can pay for higher scaling).

**Update**:

The [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) protocol and API is making rapid progress and allows a Data Channel to be established between two peers (you still may need a STUN/TURN server for the initial NAT traversal and setup).

Comment: +1. Though I wouldn't recommend third party apps. Much easier to build your own.

Comment: Pusher now provides 20 simultaneous connections and 100.000 messages per day for free :)

Comment: I think you should update your answer : 
https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-peer-peer-conversational-video

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly, that ericsson blog post is fairly old but is talking about the technology that eventually became WebRTC so I've added an update to reflect that.

Comment: @kanaka that means you still have to go through the server the first time, in order to make a peer 2 peer connection ?

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly, it's theoretically possible (http://blog.printf.net/articles/2013/05/17/webrtc-without-a-signaling-server/) but it's a very uncommon use case since just about everybody is behind a NAT firewall and you will still need some way to setup the signalling (communicate the connection details).

Comment: Years later, the internet will grind to a halt as one of the links change: http://www.ericsson.com/research-blog/context-aware-communication/beyond-html5-peer-peer-conversational-video/

Comment: As of 2017, WebRTC is a standard part of most modern browsers. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45765379/3672465

Answer (score 41):

In theory it is possible with [WebRTC DataChannel](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-rtcdatachannel):

> RTCDataChannel is a WebRTC API for high performance, low latency,
>   peer-to-peer communication of arbritary data. The API is
>   simple—similar to WebSocket—but communication occurs directly between
>   browsers, so RTCDataChannel can be much faster than WebSocket even if
>   a relay (TURN) server is required (when 'hole punching' to cope with
>   firewalls and NATs fails).

"In theory" because it isn't supported by a stable browser yet and you still need a relay server (TURN) if one of the browsers is behind a [symmetric NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Methods_of_port_translation). Nevertheless, it is a really promising feature.

**Update:** Chrome 26 and Firefox 22 support RTCDataChannel by default and Firefox 19-21 if you enable WebRTC by setting `media.peerconnection.enabled` to true (about:config).

Comment: [Today it's supported by most major browsers except Edge.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=rtcpeerconnection)

Comment: Now edge does too!

Answer (score 10):

I was reading about websocket and peer 2 peer and found [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/).

I still haven't made anything though, but by the examples it looks promising.

Comment: PeerJS is a wrapper over WebRTC.

Answer (score 4):

Now days it's possible, currently only Chrome,FF and Opera support it (desktop).

There's some libraries starting to pop up around the web right now, such as [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/) and [js-platform-p2p](https://github.com/js-platform/p2p) which pretty much simplifies things.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and reliable cross browser supported way is to use http://httprelay.io with AJAX calls. It is also implements one to many communication what could be useful for game development.