# Bind to socket using javascript?

Tags: javascript, webserver

Is it possible to bind to a socket with in-browser javascript code? I need to open a local web server when a user visits a page to provide some localhost web publishing.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: @omnosis - thank you, this is a very important point, that WebSockets only allow outbound connections. I will go ahead and use Silverlight to host an in-page localhost-available web server. You should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot listen on a port with websocket so you cannot create a local web server within a browser.
[Do websockets allow for p2p (browser to browser) communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118272/do-websockets-allow-for-p2p-browser-to-browser-communication)

But you can create javascript server with [Nodejs](http://nodejs.org/). This is also javascript, but not in the browser. This is easy, fast and lightweight.

*(i guess) javascript, silverlight, flash cant create in-browser server. they cant access to the sockets directly. the browser not allows. i think the websockets are forwarded sockets by the browser. also i dont really understand why you want to create this.*

Comment: This is always the point. Every good "not-yet" implemented idea rises reaction of a form "I don't know why would you want to implement it", when inquiring about thechincal realization. Silverlight can bind to a socket, javascript with flash can do to.

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers can use [WebSockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/), though it has [it's own protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17). Otherwise, there are solutions out there that use a hidden Flash object to do TCP sockets. One of them is [jsxmlsocket](http://code.google.com/p/jsxmlsocket/).