# Can I create a websocket server using JavaScript (client-side)?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have just seen that the [Websockets reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/WebSockets_reference$revision/848563) MDN article says

> [`WebSocketServer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WebSocketserver)
>
> Used for opening a new WebSocket server. Required information is (port, origin, location).

Then, does it mean I can create a websocket server client-side?

If that's it, does it mean I can turn this... (each arrow is a websocket connection)

[image]

...into this?

[image]

But, do browsers have the power of doing that without any router/firewall configuration?

And how can I use it? The [`WebSocketServer` link](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WebSocketserver) is broken. And I have tried searching it but I haven't found anything.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/ You can do websockets with node which is javascript.

Comment: @Dave No, I want it client-side.

Comment: do you mean you want your pc to be the server like your localhost ?

Comment: @Dave But MDN page suggests that there is some implementation client-side of a WebSocket server. And no, I don't want my PC to be the server. I want (well, I don't, it's just academical) the browsers which connect to my server to be able to connect one to each other using websockets.

Comment: You need server side which connects clients together.

Comment: @Dave But if it can't be done client-side, why does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/WebSockets_reference suggest that there is a client-side interface `WebSocketServer`?

Comment: Where does it say it is client side server? which doesn't make sense, its either client side or server side, client side can't also be server side.

Comment: @Dave It doesn't say it explicitly, that's why I say *suggests*. But next to `WebSockets` interface (which is client-side), it says `WebSocketServer`, so I guess that's another client-side interface. And when I say a client-side server I mean that clients' browsers (client-side) listen to connections from other browsers, so they act like a server

Comment: i think you're misreading something or they worded it badly.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118272/do-websockets-allow-for-p2p-browser-to-browser-communication and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022383/how-to-make-a-browser-to-browser-peer-to-peer-connection. This also looks interesting: http://peerjs.com/

Comment: Also keep in mind that MDN is a wiki, and the page you linked to is a draft.

Comment: I came here expecting to find the same answers.
Unfortunately Mozilla seems to be the only one innovating here.
Two Mozilla drafted specs I really want to see standardized is this & TCPSocket:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCPSocket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like WebSocketServer is something currently under development by Mozilla without much support or anything of the like. I searched through some of their [repositories](http://mxr.mozilla.org/) and couldn't find any references, except for in some testing code for normal WebSockets.

If what you're looking for is some form of P2P WebSockets, I don't think that's possible without some work right now. You need, as others have said, a server endpoint for the connection, something that is most popularly implemented in languages like Python and node.js

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a server-side endpoint for the WebSocket. A web socket is an open connection between the server and a client - how could you possible achieve this without a server? I don't quite understand what you are trying to convey with the diagrams, but you need to set up special configurations on the server-side to create a web socket resource like this: ws://example.com/resource so you can't arbitrarily create websockets between two clients and such.

Comment: Well, I was surprised that it could be done client-side. But if it can't be done, why does MDN page suggest that there is some implementation client-side of a WebSocket server?

Comment: @Oriol You use WebSocket using JavaScript on the client-side to connect to a web-socket resource on the server.

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/WebSockets_reference . You are talking about `WebSocket` interface (*The primary interface for connecting to a WebSocket server and then sending and receiving data on the connection*). I'm talking about `WebSocketServer` interface (*Used for opening a new WebSocket server*)

Comment: @Oriol There doesn't seem to be any documentation on `WebSocketServer` anywhere (even W3C) aside from that brief description on the MDN link you provided, so I'm inclined to believe it's still a technology in development by Mozilla. As far as I can see, it's not a part of ECMAScript.

Comment: I think WebSocketServer may be used in nodejs, but I am sure it's not used on client-side web development.

Comment: You might want to look into WebRTC. You can establish local P2P connections between browsers, but over the internet a nameserver is still required.