# Peer to Peer Socket IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am writing a proof of concept application to allow several computers to communicate with each other and control hardware that is attached to them. I would like to use Socket.IO or something like it for the connection , but I often want to send data directly from one socket client to another instead of to the socket server. This is mostly to save network traffic. Is this possible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022383/how-can-i-make-a-browser-to-browser-peer-to-peer-connection

Comment: there are newer RTC data methods that can almost do what you describe (they still need temporary access to a central server to handshake)

Comment: Imagine going to some (hacked) site and suddenly your browser acts like a server, responding to web sockets request

Comment: Maybe [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your answer might be WebRTC, described here:

[Do websockets allow for p2p (browser to browser) communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118272/do-websockets-allow-for-p2p-browser-to-browser-communication)

From an answer in the article: "The WebRTC protocol and API is making rapid progress and allows a Data Channel to be established between two peers (you still may need a STUN/TURN server for the initial NAT traversal and setup)."

Comment: The answer you refered to is oudated. The guy wrote in 2010 that _The WebRTC protocol and API is making rapid progress_. It was almost 5 years ago!

Answer (score 1):

There is a github project called socket.io-p2p which comes with a demo chat application that starts out brokered by a server but then switches to WebRTC.

The current link is https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-p2p .  That seems unlikely to disappear any time soon, but, in case it does at some future point, you should be able to find a clone/fork somewhere by knowing the socket.io-p2p name.  (It's under the MIT license.)