# Does HTML5 Support Peer-to-Peer (and not just WebSockets)

Tags: html, p2p, websocket

The language I am working in is Javascript on HTML5-compatible browsers.

My understanding is that WebSockets require a socket server to transport push notifications and messages back and forth between clients.

Is there an actual peer-to-peer capability with HTML5 that does not require a socket server?  Has anyone seen example client-side code in Javascript that exemplifies this capability?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will HTML5 allow web apps to make peer-to-peer HTTP connections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032006/will-html5-allow-web-apps-to-make-peer-to-peer-http-connections)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the answers for [Will HTML5 allow web apps to make peer-to-peer HTTP connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032006/will-html5-allow-web-apps-to-make-peer-to-peer-http-connections) However, the content in the WebSockets specification seems to have gone, so I suspect the answer now is "no".

Comment: This is incorrect, WebRTC support direct peer-to-peer communications.
And there are existing applications already who use it:
https://www.sharefest.me , https://www.peer5.com

Comment: Yes, WebRTC has indeed taken up this matter. In 2010 it wasn’t a thing, though; I believe it was more than a year before there were any stable implementations of it.

Answer (score 3):

WebRTC
http://www.webrtc.org/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC

But in 2010 it wasn’t a thing :(

Answer (score 0):

https://www.peer5.com/faq

Just seen this online, may be worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time browsers are behind firewall and you cannot connect directly to browser. If you don't want to implement server yourself there is a solution:

https://httprelay.io/

You can use AJAX calls to communicate between browsers.

Comment: I like httprelay.io  is there on github any source code similar to httprelay.io ?