# Is is possible to make a client to client connection with HTML5

Tags: html, sockets, websocket

I know that HTML5 has the new feature called WebSockets for making a connection between browser and server.

But is it possible that the server helps clients make a connection between them?

I want to transfer file from client A to client B

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does HTML5 Support Peer-to-Peer (and not just WebSockets)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181645/does-html5-support-peer-to-peer-and-not-just-websockets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, WebSockets don't (yet) help in this instance, because browsers only support the *client* half of the protocol.

It's certainly possible to have a central WebSocket server responsible for relaying messages between any set of clients, though.

Comment: Thx, but I do it for file transfer.
So, I think that it is too slow for client A send file to server and then server send to B..