# Can HTML5 Websockets connect 2 clients (browsers) directly without using a server? (P2P)

Tags: html, p2p, websocket

Using HTML5 Websockets, can I open a socket directly between 2 clients (browsers) (assuming I know their IP addresses and there are no NAT traversal issues). I want to send some data directly from one browser to another browser, essentially creating a P2P network. Everything I've read so far on the web, websockets are all used to communicate between client and server, but nothing about client to client.

Answer (score 47):

**No**

Already answered here for more details: [Do websockets allow for p2p (browser to browser) communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118272/do-websockets-allow-for-p2p-browser-to-browser-communication)

**Update**:

The [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org) protocol and API is making rapid progress and allows a Data Channel to be established between two peers (you still may need a STUN/TURN server for the initial NAT traversal and setup).

Comment: I think you need to take a look at this : 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-rtcdatachannel
https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-peer-peer-conversational-video.

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly, the Ericsson blog post is fairly old and is talking about the technology that became WebRTC.

Comment: which is `peerConnection` ?

Comment: peerConnection is one piece of WebRTC (it's the name for a big collection of technologies).

Comment: As of 2017, WebRTC is a standard part of most modern browsers. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45765379/3672465

Answer (score 7):

From past to future:  Pick your implementation.

- Most modern browsers support peer to proxy to peer using [Websockets](http://www.websocket.org/).
- Peer to peer is only available using certain browsers plug-ins for example [Opera Unite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286848/peer-to-peer-file-sharing-with-web-sockets) and [FireFox Pow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pow-plain-old-webserver/).
- Major browsers are in the process of implementing [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) which will allow peer to peer.

Answer (score 3):

If you just don't want to implement server your self you can use https://httprelay.io . No additional libraries required, all communication based on simple AJAX calls.