# Build a phonegap/cordova iOS p2p video chat

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, video, p2p

I want to build a `phonegap` video chat for public use, but I didn't find any solution for iOS.

I tried `Phonertc` for example, which looks like the only plugin built for `p2p` video, but it doesn't work at all. It's full of bugs and really not stable, what would you suggest now?

I thought about streaming in `p2p` the camera video in background using the phonegap media plugin and some services like amazon servers for relaying, I would avoid using tools like `tokbozx` and `twillio`.

I really need to be able to manage the video stream so that I can apply filters and more from a canvas for example.

Please if you have some idea let me know, thanks!!

So what do you think the steup and logic should be behind building a `cordova` video and audio `p2p` chat?
thsanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the model you're going for, but you could try p2p:
http://www.webrtc.org/architecture
[Can HTML5 Websockets connect 2 clients (browsers) directly without using a server? (P2P)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277351/can-html5-websockets-connect-2-clients-browsers-directly-without-using-a-serve)

I haven't played with server-side much, but here's a tutorial:
http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial

Client Side Only (expand from here, could add canvas):

```
<html><head>
<script>
    navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
   navigator.getUserMedia (

      // constraints
      {
         video: true,
         audio: true
      },

      // successCallback
      function(localMediaStream) {
         var video = document.querySelector('video');
         video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
         // Do something with the video here, e.g. video.play()
      },

      // errorCallback
      function(err) {
         console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
      }
   );
} else {
   console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
}
    </script>
</head><body>

<video style="border: solid 1px" autoplay="true">

</body></html>
```

Comment: iOS safari does not support webRTC anyway thanks for your answer

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm an android guy :/  hopefully the client-side portion is helpful as it should be supported on ios.  You might want to read into server-side solutions then, although that's going to make a lot of overhead that would be nice to skip.

Answer (score 0):

There is ConnectyCube platform which provides Cordova chat & video chat SDKs and code samples

Here is a Video Chat how to guide: https://developers.connectycube.com/js/code-samples-videochat-cordova

It describes how to run their Video Chat web code sample under Cordova/PhoneGap. Looks pretty simple. It's based on top of WebRTC API, it's a P2P video chat. They use **cordova-plugin-iosrtc** plugin for iOS to work