# Socket.IO local connection between two browser windows

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I have two web applications, App1 & App2  - and when App1 is running on the same machine, App2 need to know that and required to talk to App1. They can be running in different browsers. 
Socket.IO seems like a good option, but couldn't find a way to actually detect App1's open port. Is there any way in Socket.io or any other javascript frameworks to communicate between two browser windows?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can HTML5 Websockets connect 2 clients (browsers) directly without using a server? (P2P)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277351/can-html5-websockets-connect-2-clients-browsers-directly-without-using-a-serve)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277351/can-html5-websockets-connect-2-clients-browsers-directly-without-using-a-serve

Comment: There is no supported "machine ID" to identify a particular computer that works across browsers.  As such, you cannot count on reliably identifying two different connections from two different browsers as coming from the same computer.  There are various "fingerprint" techniques that try to examine the state of the local browser environment (sometimes including plugins) to try to create a fingerprint that might identify a particular computer, but this is not foolproof.  Within the same browser, you can use a cookie to identify two request from different windows in the same browser.