# Is it possible to create peer-to-peer connections in a web browser?

Tags: html, connection, p2p

I am aware that an early draft of HTML5 specified peer-to-peer connections using the [PeerToPeerConnection()](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080122/#peer-to-peer) constructor. However, this was [replaced](http://dev.w3.org/html5/pubnotes/Overview.html#network_wd2) by WebSocket which, to my knowledge, does not support peer-to-peer connections.

In addition, the [device element](http:///www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/commands.html#devices) specifies a [peer-to-peer connection interface](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/commands.html#devices), however no web browsers have implemented it yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will HTML5 allow web apps to make peer-to-peer HTTP connections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032006/will-html5-allow-web-apps-to-make-peer-to-peer-http-connections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Opera Unite](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-unite-developer-primer-revisited/) allows Peer to peer (basically gives your browser web server, file system and nat-traversal capabilities), but this is Opera only.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly P2P, but you can use proxy server using push mechanism

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

For example if you want to send data from Browser A to Browser B, you send that data to proxy server and that server push it to Browser B.