# Is possible client-client communication in modern browsers?

Tags: php, html, web, webserver, websocket

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to create peer-to-peer connections in a web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628125/is-it-possible-to-create-peer-to-peer-connections-in-a-web-browser)
>   [How to make a browser to browser (peer to peer) connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022383/how-to-make-a-browser-to-browser-peer-to-peer-connection)

Communications like chat or file transfer with PHP, normally is `client-server-client` with help of Ajax or Comet (Ajax pooling), Exist a way for start communication `client-server-client` ( for server present clients each other) and after `client-client` ?

Comment: ... and even those grow from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032006/will-html5-allow-web-apps-to-make-peer-to-peer-http-connections (which is updated from time to time, and does not fall out of time completely).

Comment: But the duplicates questions and answers are from two years ago, and include specific tecnologies (adobe,opera,etc) and not standard like html5