# Will Websockets allow a server to run in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

Are there any plans for a Websockets listen function?

Allowing peer to peer applications in the browser could be revolutionary.

I found this answer: [Will HTML5 allow web apps to make peer-to-peer HTTP connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032006/will-html5-allow-web-apps-to-make-peer-to-peer-http-connections/1032150#1032150) but it is rather old. I think the specification it refers to (the Connection api) has now been replaced with Websockets, which does not mention any listen facility.

Answer (score 14):

The [WebSockets API](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/complete/network.html#network)  does not provide a way to listen for connections; it is client only.

You might be interested in [Opera Unite](https://dev.opera.com/blog/taking-the-web-into-our-own-hands/).

**Update:**

Also check out [pusherapp](http://pusherapp.com/). It's a WebSockets service online. They charge for over 5 clients, but it's super simple to setup and use. Depending on what your p2p application requirements are, it might suffice.

Comment: I know it doesn't now but it is very new and changing and I hoped that it might be planned or considered for a future version.

I was interested in Unite but upon examination found it to be unpleasantly proprietary and tied to Opera's servers. It does seem to enable the sort of thing I would like to see done though.

Comment: I've been participating in the working group and I don't see a server/listen mode on the horizon anytime soon.

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but I was wondering the same thing, and came across peer-server, which might be worth having a look at. It uses WebRTC, and looks like it does what you're thinking:

https://github.com/PeerServer/peer-server

Answer (score 3):

Tangentially related to your question, but you did say "p2p in the browser", so..

The Flash player has [p2p APIs](http://www.flashrealtime.com/tuts/p2p-in-flash.html) that allow direct connection with other peers (typically other browsers) over UDP.

The APIs are geared toward using those connections for voice/video streaming, but it seems possible to use them for generic message passing as well.

The tricky point of course is "how do peers find each others?". Currently, Adobe offers a free/beta service to do that, called [Cirrus (formerly Stratus)](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/). It's also possible to buy Flash Media servers from Adobe to do the same (which also provide TCP server-based fallbacks for folks that are behind UDP-unfriendly firewalls.) Presumably, open-source alternatives like [Red5](http://red5.org/) will have support for it too at some point.

Comment: That sounds like it could be suitable. Another way is with a java applet which can use RMI. These are options for right now but it would be good to see a standard solution that does not require plugins.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for a generic browser solution, for non secure and limited connections you may use a Google Chrome extension to do the job:

Web Server for Chrome

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb