# Is it possible to open a port in Javascript for communication on the network?

Tags: javascript, server, p2p, peer

I saw that Socket.IO and Websockets usually require NodeJS or similar but don't run on clients.

Is there any possible way to open a port for accepting communications using JavaScript? So devices can talk to each other on a network, peer2peer (acting like a server)?

Comment: browser extensions may be able to. javascript running in webpages is not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can't use real TCP or UDP sockets in the browser.
2. You may use WebSockets to communicate to a server which translates WebSocket connection to real socket connection. Server may be written in NodeJS or other language/platform.
3. You [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786352/will-websockets-allow-a-server-to-run-in-the-browser) listen for connections with WebSockets.
4. You also may use [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org), which is also different from sockets, but better suited for peer-to-peer networks (I don't know very much about it).