# Get client to act as server with websocket?

Tags: html, client-server, websocket

I am basically writing an almost purely clientside application (there is a webserver which can be used to store some persistent data, but its easier to forget about it), but as part of this I was looking to add some functionality akin to hosting a game.

The scenario would be 1 person would host the game via their browser (open a TCP socket awaiting connections), then X other people would connect to that server and join. The server would be in charge of receiving and sending data between clients.

So in this scenario is it possible to host a websocket server within a webpage?

I was looking at trying to do something peer to peer style, but I don't think it is currently supported, but its not a major problem as its only going to be for sending small amounts of text and some update messages between clients.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will HTML5 allow web apps to make peer-to-peer HTTP connections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032006/will-html5-allow-web-apps-to-make-peer-to-peer-http-connections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebSocket browser API is client only (for the foreseeable future).

In some sense, WebRTC us peer-to-peer, but even if the WebRTC API adds the ability to send arbitrary data, you still need a STUN/TURN server to establish the initial connection.

Comment: Oh well :( As far as initial connection goes I would be happy enough to  make the clients manually add in the IP address or whatever. I guess it does kind of fall under peer-to-peer to a degree, but that insinuates that clients are all equals, but in this case there are some things the server would do clients would not.