# Internet connection code using html5

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will HTML5 allow web apps to make peer-to-peer HTTP connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032006/will-html5-allow-web-apps-to-make-peer-to-peer-http-connections)

I want to make a Internet connection from one device to another how to do the coding of it using html5 and javascript

Comment: 1. what have you tried? 2. what do you mean with an internet connection between two devices?

Comment: i m trying to use Web Socket. is it the right way to do it?. by internet connection between two device i mean if one device enable the hotspot connection of it then another device can use the connection of first device by providing authentication

Comment: @Quentin it may well be a duplicate, but the accepted answer on that question is wrong.

Comment: @infodeve1 no, that's completely outside the realms of what you can do with Javascript.  If you want the first device to act as a _router_ for the second, that first device must provide NAT and native IP services to the second.

Comment: @Alnitak — So provide a better answer on that question rather than leaving the bad information there unchallenged.

Comment: @Quentin someone already did - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1032171/6782 - but it only has two upvotes

Comment: how to provide the NAT and native IP services? can you please explain

Comment: @infodeve1 that's why I'm saying - you can't.  Doing that requires operating system level features.

Comment: is it possible to do it in Android in place of html5?

Answer (score 1):

You can't - at least not directly.

Not only does JS not include any suitable APIs, but things like NAT devices tend to get in the way of device-to-device connections.

Possible work arounds include having both devices make a connection to a central server, perhaps using WebSockets.

Comment: i don't want a any web server between them is it possible

Comment: @infodeve1 : no. it's not currently possible without it