# Websocket and reception of a message

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, boost-asio

I try to make a server "messages" via websocket under boost.
Currently, I can often send large messages or series of messages from the server.
when I hit "send", it sends tons of data.
The difficulty is that when the server receives a command in a websocket message like "Stop", "Pause" ... this command runs until the end of the previous message. I try to stop the execution of the previous command.

I tried to read the buffer between sending data. but it does not work. I try to check if there is one receiving orders with async_read_some.

I based on the example of
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/443660/Building-a-basic-HTML5-client-server-application
and HTTP server boost
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

Do you have any idea? I reworked my code several times but I can not execute the new real-time control as it appears at the end ..

thank you

Comment: I find a solution with the creation of a function in a thread launched at each analysis of new buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If the data has already been sent to the network adapter, there is very little you can do to alter the order of packets. Network adapter will send the packets as and when it gets round to it, in the order you've queued them.

If you want to be able to send "higher priority" messages, then don't send off all the data in one go, but hold it in a queue waiting for the device to accept more data, and if a high priority message comes in, send that before you send any of the other packets off.

Don't make the packets TOO small, but I guess if you make packets that are a few kilobytes or so at a time, it will work quite swiftly and still allow good control over the flow.

Of course, this also will require that the receiver has the understanding of "there may be different 'flows' or 'streams' of information, and if you send a 'pause' command, it means that the previously sent stream is not going to receive anything until 'resume' is sent" obviously adjust this as needed for the behaviour you need, but you do need some way to not just say "put 'STOP' as data into the rest of the flow", but interpret it as a command.

Comment: thank you. My approach is similar to what you offer.
Currently, I send my data into several pieces through the messages. I'm trying without success between each sending messages, to test to see if I have a message like "Stop" to start a function to finish sending the remaining pieces of data
I try to perform a capture buffer and reading to see if there was meanwhile a new message received.
It does not work. However, the following command is received but arrives
On the one hand I get messages containing commands, on the other hand, I run these commands and I send the answers via messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you send large message in the network as a single packet by the time server receives all the data the server receives stop message you may not have control over it until you complete receiving data.

It's better you implement priority message queue. Send the message as small chunks from client and assemble server instead of single large packet. Give message packets like stop(cancel) high priority. While receiving the messages at server end if any high priority message exists like stop(cancel) you don't need to accept remaining messages you can close the websocket connection at server.

Read the thread [Chunking WebSocket Transmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010354/chunking-websocket-transmission) for more info.

Comment: Hello,

thank you.
My code takes into account the size of messages and priorities, but the problem is that I can not catch new messages between two programs. Each receipt, it examines the received message and determines the command (and the function) in the message but during the "send", not whether it has received new messages.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Boost, have you looked at [WebSocket++](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp) (Boost/ASIO based)?

Comment: Hello,

I wanted subsequently used websocket + + but it would take me more time and I was not sure it helps me. I found the solution later with threads.
thank you