# Websocket connection closes with 1006

Tags: javascript, websocket

when the size of the websocket frame is more than 50MB, then the socket connection closes automatically. I am not sure why there is a size limit?

I am using Javascript Websocket. Is the client closing the connection or the server disconnects from the client?

This happens for only large size. Smaller chunks works fine.

Can someone throw some help here?

Comment: I believe this has been already [answered more generally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010354/chunking-websocket-transmission). For specific advice, I think you need to detail which browser and server platform you're using, and whether or not a proxy or reverse proxy is in use. I'm pretty sure 1006 always means the client closed the connection.

Comment: I am using Chrome without proxy...This is running in a VM with 8GB SSD.

Comment: As explained in [the second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13049499/7061430) in the thread I linked to, the [RFC reccomends setting a limit](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-10.4), so this behaviour is by design. Perhaps it would be better to reframe your question in terms of what you're trying to achieve with such large frames?