# How can I receive data with a peerJS peer to peer connection?

Tags: javascript, html, p2p, peerjs

I'm trying to connect two peers using peerJS. I am pretty much just following through their "Getting Started" but I am still struggling. Below is the code that I have gotten so far.

```
<body>
<script src="http://cdn.peerjs.com/0.3/peer.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var conn;
    var peer = new Peer({key: 'lwjd5qra8257b9'});
    peer.on('open', function(id){
        console.log('My peer ID is:' + id);
        document.getElementById('peerIdDisplay').innerHTML = '<b>My peer ID is: </b><font color="red">' + id + '</font>';
    });     

    function ConnectToPeer()
    {
        var peerId = document.getElementById("peerIdTxtBox").value;
        console.log(peerId);
        conn = peer.connect(peerId);

        AfterConnInit();

        peer.on('error', function(err){
            console.log('error');
        });

    };

    peer.on('connection', function(conn) 
    { 
        console.log('connected');
    });


    function AfterConnInit()
    {

        conn.on('open', function() {
        // receive messages
        conn.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('received', data);
        });

        //send messages
        conn.send('hello');

        });
    };


    function SendMessage()
    {
        //conn.send('Hello!');
    };

</script>
<p id='peerIdDisplay' style='font-family:verdana'><b>My peer ID is: </b></p>
<hr style='width:100%'/>
<p id='instructions'>Enter another peer's ID to connect to them..</p>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="peerIdTxtBox">
</form>
<button id="conToPeerBtn" OnClick="ConnectToPeer()">Connect To Peer</button>
<button id="sendMessageBtn" OnClick="SendMessage()">Send Message</button>
</body>
```

I have managed to get a connection between the two peers using a generated peerID, however, I can't seem to get my head around sending and receiving messages. From what I can understand the conn.send() is supposed to send the message to the client which then receives it, but I don't know how to /get/ the data to display on the other peer, let alone send it using a SendMessage function from the first peer. Can someone PLEASE explain how the data is sent and received before my computer goes out the window?

Thanks

Comment: possibly related: ["Will HTML5 allow web apps to make peer-to-peer HTTP connections?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032006/will-html5-allow-web-apps-to-make-peer-to-peer-http-connections)

Answer (score 2):

The `'data'` event was being listened inside the `conn.on('open')`, moving it as an independent event handler  will get the code working.

Below is the modified code

```
<script>
var conn;
var peer = new Peer({key: 'lwjd5qra8257b9'});

peer.on('open', function(id){
    console.log('My peer ID is:' + id);
    document.getElementById('peerIdDisplay').innerHTML = '<b>My peer ID is: </b><font color="red">' + id + '</font>';
});     

function ConnectToPeer()
{
    var peerId = document.getElementById("peerIdTxtBox").value;
    console.log(peerId);
    conn = peer.connect(peerId);


    peer.on('error', function(err){
        console.log('error');
    });

};

peer.on('connection', function(conn) 
{ 

    console.log('peer connected');
    conn.on('open', function() {
        console.log('conn open');
    });
    conn.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});


function SendMessage()
{
    conn.send('Hello!');
};
```